# Nuclear physics Radioactivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

90Sr has a half life of 28.5y. It is chemically similar to Ca and enters the body through the food  chain and collects in bones. It is a serious health hazard. How long in (years) will it take for    99.99% of Sr released in a nuclear reactor accident     to disappear?

Answer (score 3):

If initial mass is $M$. Amount remaining after $n$ half lives is $M/2^{n}$.

Ask yourself, **How much remains after 99.99% is gone?**

Equate.

Comment: I think the poster was hoping to get an answer that accounted for the determination of some real value of M.

Answer (score 3):

Pratik's point was a good one, though perhaps not the most helpful.

The decay of a radioactive material means that the amount of time for any specific percentage of a quantity of material to decay is constant.  That is, in this case,

$0.0001 N_0 = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}$

$t = -\frac{\ln(0.0001)}{\lambda}$

where $\lambda$ is called the decay constant.  In this case we have

$t \approx 379 \mbox{years}$

---

What you really should care about is the effect of this material.  When making these sorts of calculations for accident analysis, engineers consider, a huge variety of factors such as:

- amount of fuel in reactor,
- original composition of fuel,
- history of fuel (reactor operation),
- relative liklihood of different types of accident,
- relative liklihood of the release of refractory products (material from the core),
- likely percent of refractory products released to the environment,
- relative liklihood of dispersion of various refractory products (considering half-life, air bouyancy, diffusion factors, etc.),
- potential containment measures and all of the possibilities that go into their success or failure,
- decay chains of environmental contaminants
- environmental vectors for human exposure
- relative effect of various levels of exposure
- relative effect of type (inhalation, consumption, skin, etc.) of exposure
- etc., etc.

There is an entire field known as probabilistic risk assesment that examines these sorts of questions and debates the relative weights that should be placed on them.  I am not a PRA expert, but I have some experience with the field.

That being said, we, unfortunately, have some real data with which we can work.  In the case of Fukushima, the level of ${}^90$Sr in seawater some 7 months after the accident was less than $0.03 Bq/cm^3$; see [this](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/incidents/pdfs/press/20111012/foreign-press-briefing-20111012-nsc.pdf) article.  [Another source](http://news.xinhuanet.com/english2010/world/2011-10/13/c_131189797.htm) gives a value of 195 Bq.  This equates to about $4 \times 10^{-11}$ grams... not very much.  Considering that the deposition fraction (the amount that gets into bones once consumed/inhaled) is about 0.12, these quantities are quite minimal.

In short, it's not something you need to lose sleep over.

Comment: If the half-life is 28.5 yr, then your 1.5 d can't be right. I think you've calculated the time for 0.01% of the sample to decay. Pratik's answer would give 13.3 half-lives or 379 years.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  Fixed now